# I am having trouble with my first project in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

Here's my index action in the books controller: http://pastebin.com/XdtGRQKV

Here's the view for the action i just mentioned: http://pastebin.com/nQFy400m

Here's the result without being logged in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gExcX.jpg

Here's the result when i'm logged in with the user 'admin': [http://i.imgur.com/E1CUr.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/E1CUr.jpg)

So the problem is that, in the view, before line 25 the 'user' variable seems to be empty ( or not loaded), and after line 25 the variable 'user' has the expected values.

I have tried initializing a variable in the index method of the books controller but get exactly the same results.

Thanks in advance!

BTW had to make the links text because of stackoverflow limit.

Comment: It might be better if you don't just link to the sources and what's happening, but actually put them in your question. I sure as hell don't want to open FOUR different links just to know what you're asking!

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

should be in controller, not in view (MVC!) like this:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

Then in your view, as @Voyta answered, use `<%= @user.username %>`. Code inside `<% %>` is evaluated, but not rendered, so if you want to put result in your html, you need to add `=`.

And all yours `if user` and `if user.admin == 1` would look much better this way:

```
<% if user %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
  <% if user.admin == 1 %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', book, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  <% end
 end
%>
```

If you use `if` in single line like here:

```
<%
 if user
  if user.admin == 1
%>
<%= link_to 'New book', new_book_path %>
<%
  end
end
%>
```

You can write the same like this:

```
<%= link_to 'New book', new_book_path if user && user.admin == 1 %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't output `user.username`. It should be `<%= user.username %>`, not `<% user.username %>`